# XHR POST: to API Controller works, to Razor Page fails

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a standard ASP.NET Core Web application created from the Visual Studio template. I have a razor page which issues an XHR POST request with a payload upon a change event.

If I make the url of the request an api controller in the application (i.e. under `Controllers` folder), the request succeeds.

If I make the same request, same payload to a razor page method (under `Pages` folder), it fails with http 400.

Both methods have the same signature.

Can anyone describe why the behaviour is different?

I would essentially like to use the facility in razor pages to POST to a handler method from an XHR.

`UserController.cs`

```cs
namespace Athena.Web.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        public void Post([FromBody]object postedObj)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

`Usr.cshtml.cs`

```cs
namespace Athena.Web.Pages.Users
{
    public class UsrModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnPostActionHere([FromBody]object postedObj)
        {
            ...        
        }

        public void OnPost([FromBody]object postedObj)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

`Usr.cshtml`

```cs
@page "{handler?}"
@model Athena.Web.Pages.Users.UsrModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>User</h1>
```

I can't post the XHR call because it's coming from a third-party Syncfusion control but the calling page is basically:

`Index.cshtml`

```html
<ejs-grid id="grid">
    <e-data-manager updateUrl="/api/User" insertUrl="/Home/Usr" adaptor="UrlAdaptor">
...
</ejs-grid>
```

Comment: Post your actual code - your razor page method code, calling code, controller code. It is possible to send a Post to a Razor page.

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XHR Post requests invariably fail when targeted at a Razor Page handler method with a 400 Bad Request because you haven't included the request verification token in the request, either as a form field, or a header.

https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/336/ajax-posts-in-razor-pages-and-http-400-errors

the easiest way to generate a token is by including a `<form>` element with the method set to `post`, and then you can include the token in the request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/",
    data: { foo: "bar" },
    headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
    success: function (response) {
```